# Why are the 'Genre' data not written into the .csv file in my code

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to learn web scraping using beautifulsoup and I have implemented this code. But only movie titles are being written into the csv file but not Genre although both of them have been retrieved.

URL: http://www.imdb.com/search/title?sort=num_votes,desc&start=1&title_type=feature&year=1950,2012

```
f = csv.writer(open('movie-names.csv', 'w'))
f.writerow(['Title', 'Genre'])

pages = []
genre;


for i in range(1,2):
    url = 'http://www.imdb.com/search/title?sort=num_votes,desc&start=1&title_type=feature&year=1950,2012'
    pages.append(url)


for item in pages:
    page = requests.get(item)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

    movie_titles = soup.find_all(class_ = 'lister-item-content')

    for movie_title in movie_titles:
        title = movie_title.find('a').contents[0]
        genre = movie_title.find_all(class_ = 'genre')[0].get_text()
        print(genre)
        f.writerow([title, genre])
```

Comment: Is `genre;` at the beginning of you code a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pandas` it is much easier to export data in `CSV`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
pages = []

for i in range(1,2):
    url = 'http://www.imdb.com/search/title?sort=num_votes,desc&start=1&title_type=feature&year=1950,2012'
    pages.append(url)

Movie_title=[]
Movie_genre=[]
for item in pages:
    page = requests.get(item)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

    movie_titles = soup.select('.lister-item-content')

    for movie_title in movie_titles:
        title = movie_title.select_one('a').text
        Movie_title.append(title)
        genre = movie_title.select_one('.genre').text.replace('\n','')
        Movie_genre.append(genre)


df = pd.DataFrame({"Movie_title":Movie_title,"Movie_genre":Movie_genre})
df.to_csv("movie-names.csv",index=False)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This works but still cant understand why the other implementation didnt work for me. Probably difference in versions?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

with open("movie-names.csv", "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['Title', 'Genre'])

    pages = []
    genre = []


    for i in range(1,2):
        url = 'http://www.imdb.com/search/title?sort=num_votes,desc&start=1&title_type=feature&year=1950,2012'
        pages.append(url)


    for item in pages:
        page = requests.get(item)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

        movie_titles = soup.find_all(class_ = 'lister-item-content')

        for movie_title in movie_titles:
            title = movie_title.find('a').contents[0]
            genre = movie_title.find_all(class_ = 'genre')[0].get_text()
            print(title, genre)
            writer.writerow([title, genre])
```

This is an excerpt of the content in the .csv I get running the code:

```
Title   Genre
The Shawshank Redemption     Drama            
The Dark Knight  Action, Crime, Drama            
Inception    Action, Adventure, Sci-Fi            
Fight Club   Drama            
Pulp Fiction     Crime, Drama            
Forrest Gump     Drama, Romance
```

Note that this for loop:

```
for i in range(1,2):
    url = 'http://www.imdb.com/search/title?sort=num_votes,desc&start=1&title_type=feature&year=1950,2012'
    pages.append(url)
```

is going to be useless, as in this case append just one url. In the general case where `2` is `n`, it appends **the same** url `n-1` times. Is that your intention?

Comment: Unfortunately nope. The problem still persists :(

Comment: I get a csv with two columns and 51 rows, look at my answer.